# Integration Testing for Google Cloud Apis

Tags: google-api, google-data-catalog

I am new to the google apis and i am using google data catalog api for collecting metadata in my repository.
I have done unit testing using mockito framework.
But for integration testing, i am struggling a bit as it is using grpc calls internally to call google server and i have to mock them for real time scenario.
Anyone has any idea how to integration test these apis.

i have tried creating grpc server and mocking the call, but everytime i am getting channel not available error message.

Comment: Why would you mock the google server for your integration test?

Could you instead make your test talk to the same google server, but use a test-only repository or something like that?